# Author's profile picture throws 404 error in blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

In the [Stack Overflow blog authors](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/)  page, the following author's profile picture is not displaying. The console throws 404 error for those authors.

[Cassie Stone](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/sassiestone/)

> GET https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/uZI85.jpg 404 ()

[Kurtis Beavers](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/kjbeavers/)

> GET https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/UkJgG.jpg 404 ()

[Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/nickcraver/)

> GET https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/nGCYr.jpg 404 ()

[Steve Feldman](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/stevvve/)

> GET https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/RvicD.png 404 ()

Comment: I'm seeing more 404s, do you too? For example, for Cassie Stone I'm also seeing 404 for https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/19538599.png and https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/UkJgG.jpg.

Comment: For most of those, it looks like they made an error when transitioning from Imgur to their own Wordpress hosted images. For example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGCYr.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZI85.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvicD.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkJgG.jpg do work, which is what they originally used, according to what I found on the Wayback machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fixed these. Thanks for finding this!